# Groovy - regex between two characters

Tags: regex, groovy

I have this list:

```
def parsed_list = [29/29(100%), 36/36(100%), 32/32(100%), 18/18(100%), 18/18(100%), 6/6(100%)]
```

I would like to extract percentage values: 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100

I'm using this regex:

```
 \((.*?)\%
```

I'm trying with these piece of code:

```
def reg = parsed_test_case =~ \((.*?)\%
```

but I get this error:

```
unexcpected char: '\'
```

What should I improve?

Comment: You need `/\((.*?)\%/`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of Strings:

```
def parsed_list = ['29/29(100%)', '36/36(10%)', '32/32(100%)', '18/18(100%)', '18/18(100%)', '6/6(100%)']
```

Then you can do:

```
def percentages = parsed_list*.find(/\d+%/)
```

To get another list of strings:

```
[100%, 10%, 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%]
```

Comment: For this line: def percentages = parsed_list*.find(/\d+%/) I get: spread not yet supported for CPS transformation

Comment: You forgot to say this was in Jenkins